# Creating raster by interpolating point values using GeoTools

Tags: raster, vector, interpolation, geotools

I am new in using GeoTools (8.2). I was able to create shp from asc file which contains my data.

Is there a simple way to create (interpolate) a simple shapefile (only points) to raster image?

Comment: The documentation provides evidence of ways to build various raster and image files at http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/coverage/index.html.  It does not appear to supply interpolation methods, but there are myriad ways to interpolate data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Barnes Surface process using code like this:

```
public GridCoverage2D interpolate(SimpleFeatureCollection features, String value) {
    Name pName = new NameImpl("vec", "BarnesSurface");
    org.geotools.process.Process process = Processors.createProcess(pName);

    ProcessExecutor engine = Processors.newProcessExecutor(2);

    ReferencedEnvelope bounds = features.getBounds();
    double aspectRatio = bounds.getHeight() / bounds.getWidth();
    int width = 1000;
    int height = (int) (aspectRatio * width);
    Map<String, Object> input = new KVP("data", features, "valueAttr", value, "scale", 1000, "queryBuffer", 1000,
        "outputBBOX", bounds, "outputWidth", width, "outputHeight", height);

    Progress working = engine.submit(process, input);

    Map<String, Object> result = null;
    try {
      result = working.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } // get is BLOCKING

    return (GridCoverage2D) result.get("result");
  }
```